# Unable to Connect Firebase to XCode App Using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I have followed the instructions listed [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html). However, I am unable to connect my app to Firebase. I am new to iOS programming and have installed CocoaPods to add the dependency. I am receiving the error "No Such Module Firebase."

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you build anyway?

Comment: I continue to receive that compiler error.

Comment: Have you tried the usual? 1: Clean project 2: Clean derived data 3: Update pods. This is the routine you do first when you get this kind of issue (which is often caused by Xcode's cache *and/or* botched pods install).

Comment: You should have a file in your Firebase Sample folder called Firebase Sample.xcworkspace. Can you verify that file is there and it's the one you are clicking on to open your project? Second thing; can you post your pod file, which is located in the Pods folder in your project->Podfile.

Comment: What is the easiest way to clean the project and update the pods?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Try cleaning the app and then building it. If not, upload a picture of your podfile.

Also, after installing the pod, you need to close XCode and launch your project through terminal by going to the project directory and running

```
open <YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>.xcworkspace
```

in order to get access to the pods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I just open the file in the folder or does it have to be through the terminal?

Comment: That might work, just make sure you're opening the .xcworkspace file and not the .xcodeproj file.

Several tutorials online say to open the file through terminal, but I don't see why just opening the file from Finder should not work.

Comment: I have included an image of the podfile

Comment: `platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!



pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'

`

- Have your podfile look like this.
- Run pod install again
- Try opening the .xcworkspace file through terminal
- Cmd-Shift-K to clean the file
- Cmd-B to build the file

That should fix it.

Comment: yeah. put it on 3 separate lines. Not sure how to do the formatting in a comment. platform on one line, use_frameworks on second, then pod Firebase on 3rd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109198/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-nishant-roy).

Comment: Thanks this advice seems to have helped me establish the connection.